# Application from Android Studio is not installed

Tags: android-studio

The application from Android Studio is not installed. My application not installed on my device. Android Studio next shows the window.
[image]

I deleted this app from device.
Version android studio 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem when I moved my project location from one folder to another, then I just cleaned and rebuilt my project it worked out for me

Build->Clean Project
Build->Rebuilt Project

I hope it works for you too :)